# Networkx isomorphism return one-to-one correspondence

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, matching, isomorphism

With python library networkx it is possible to check for isomorphism using function `is_isomorphic(G1, G2)` where G1 and G2 are two graphs (https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/isomorphism.html).

But how to get the one-to-one node correspondence of the isomorphism after having checked that there exists one?

Let's say we perform node matching exclusively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way to go, that was actually here: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/isomorphism.vf2.html

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import isomorphism
G1 = nx.path_graph(4) # create super simple graphs
G2 = nx.path_graph(4)
GM = isomorphism.GraphMatcher(G1,G2)
GM.is_isomorphic()
GM.mapping # prints the matching/mapping
```